# Give a recursive function r on A that reverses a string

Tags: function, recursion

I really need help with this task here. Im stuck at it and I really would appreciate your help

Here is the task:

> Give a recursive function *r* on *A* that reverses a string. For instance,
>   *r(logikk) = kkigol* and *r(moro) = orom*. (given that *A* the amount of
>   letters in the Norwegian alphabet which has 29 letters.). Define the
>   function in such a way that it is correctly regardless of what *A* are.

Also *logikk* means *logic* in norwegian, and *moro* means *fun* in norwegian in case you're wondering.

I've tried to google on how I can solve tasks like this, but I had no luck. I hope I can get the help I need here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "given that A the amount of letters in the Norwegian alphabet which has 29 letters." This does not make sense.

Comment: This question belongs on cs.stackexchange.com since it is a theoretical problem. The practical solution would not use recursion. (Real-world programming problems do not tell you what technique to use to solve a program. You get to choose the best technique for the job.)

Comment: @RaymondChen the real-world solution *may* not use recursion, but recursion would be a fine way to do it.

Comment: It is still wrong to dictate how a problem must be solved. (There is really no benefit to using recursion here. It consumes stack proportional to word length and the nonrecursive version is straightforward. Besides, most languages have a built-in `reverse` function. Use it.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:

1. Define a function that takes a string argument.
2. If that argument is an empty string, return it. (Hint: this is not the *best* base case.)
3. Otherwise, return the last character of the string concatenated onto … what?

What is recursion?

If you think about the two questions here, you will have the answer.

(This answer is an attempt to stick to the spirit of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the algorithm. I hope it would help you.

```
public String r(String str){

        if(str.length() <= 1){
            return str;
        } else {
           String reverse += str.charAt(str.length()-1)
                    + r(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
            return reverse;
        }
    }
```